# If a divine caster casts (greater) anyspell is it a divine spell or an arcane spell?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, spellcasting

Pretty straightforward. The *(greater) anyspell* spells, from the Spell domain, let you cast "any arcane spell" up to a certain level. But if the caster is a divine caster, is the spell cast as an arcane spell now, or is that just the selection criterion and it gets cast as a divine spell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Spells cast via *(greater) anyspell* are arcane.

In addition to the text already quoted in the question:

> Anyspell allows you to read and prepare any arcane spell of up to 2nd level.

...the spell also clarifies further in its description (SpC, p. 14):

> When you cast the arcane spell, it works just as though cast by a wizard of your cleric level except that your Wisdom score sets the save DC (if applicable).

Given that the spell cast via *anyspell* is repeatedly referred to as arcane, and works "just as though cast by a wizard" (aside from the save DC calculation), I think it's pretty clearly cast as an arcane spell.

### Check with your DM before using this for shenanigans.

This interpretation naturally lends itself to some silly and probably unintended outcomes, such as using Spell domain Cleric to qualify for arcane casting prestige classes.

I think such shenanigans probably work by strictest RAW, but as always, if you're planning to do this kind of cheese, it's good practice to run it past your DM first to make sure you won't interfere with the kind of game they want to run.  Trying to sneak it in, or haranguing your DM into allowing it, will just make you a headache for everyone.